# Como guardar todas las filas que genera mi formulario en mysql +php + javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script>

function guardar(){

    var _nom = document.getElementById("nomb").value;
    var _cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
    var _stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;


    var fila="<tr><td>"+_nom+"</td><td>"+_cat+"</td><td>"+_precio+"</td><td>"+_stock+"</td></tr>";


    var btn = document.createElement("TR");
    btn.innerHTML=fila;
    document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

<form action="guardar_bandas.php" id="" method="post">

        Nombre: <input id="nomb" name="nomb[]" style="margin:10px" type="text"><br><br>
        Categoria:<input id="cat"  name="cat[]" style="margin:4px" type="text"><br><br>
        Precio: <input id="precio" name="precio[]" style="margin:20px" type="text"><br><br>
        Stock: <input id="stock"   name="stock[]" style="margin:25px" type="text"><br><br>


        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
 <br><br>

<input class="md-trigger boton" data-modal="fodors" type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btn_inicia"/>

 </form>

 <br><br>

<button id="btn_guardar" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button><br><br>
```

Luego sigue el procesar que seria el archivo: `guardar_bandas` en donde tengo uso un `for` para que recorra el arreglo pero al momento de guardar los registros, solo inserta el ultimo registro.

el código funciona de la siguiente manera:

lleno los datos de cada `input` luego presiono el botón guardar y mediante `javascript` trae allí mismo una fila con la información, para luego presionar el botón enviar que esta dentro del `form` y que me guarde toda la información de cada fila que se cree.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El motivo por el que siempre te guarda el ultimo registro es porque los registros introducidos anteriormente no están en una etiqueta **input** valida que pueda enviarse al darle click al botón de Enviar del formulario, para ello tu codigo que inserta las nuevas filas de la tabla debería verse mas o menos así:

```
    <script>
    function guardar(){

        var _nom = document.getElementById("nomb").value;
        var _cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
        var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
        var _stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;

        //Agregamos la informacion en etiquetas input para que puedan ser enviadas por el formulario
        //Y agregamos el atributo readonly para que no se pueda editar la información
        var fila="<tr><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='nomb[]' value='"+_nom+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='cat[]' value='"+_cat+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='precio[]' value='"+_precio+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='stock[]' value='"+_stock+"' readonly>"+
            "</td></tr>";

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Buenas, bien ahora si funciona, pero tengo el siguiente problema, estoy ingresando dos filas A y B al momento de guardar en la base de datos guarda pimero B luego A y luego nuevamente B. sera que es por lo que tengo un for en el procesar?

Comment: @KunovishPotrevi Eso se debe a que tus input que ocupas para generar tu tabla se encuentra dentro del bloque del form, para solucionar eso, solo mueve tu etiqueta <form action="guardar_bandas.php" id="" method="post"> después de los inputs que lees con javascript. osea, debajo de la etiqueta Stock: <input id="stock"   name="stock[]" style="margin:25px" type="text"><br><br>

Comment: Ese era el problema, de verdad muchas gracias, excelente solcuión.

Comment: De nada @KunovishPotrevi, no olvides marcar la respuesta como, solucion. :D